# Trouble installing towerjs on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, npm, towerjs

I keep getting this error when the towerjs post install script runs

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open '/home/claire/.npm/e18f6569-thub-com-viatropos-coffeecup-git.lock'
```

I've tried sudo, and -g but I think it's because the post install script doesn't include sudo. I can install coffeecup on its own, but the tower sub install fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login with `root` to finish installation correctly.

For Ubuntu:

1. Set `root` password if it not defined yet:

   ```
   sudo passwd
   ```
2. Change user to `root`

   ```
   su
   ```
3. Install `tower`

   ```
   npm install tower -g
   ```

This way works for me.

**Note**: not work if you change user to `root` with `sudo -s` command. Works only with `su`.